# No developer folder

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, xcode

I bought a new MacBook Pro and installed Xcode but I don't have the developer folder. What is the problem?
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Where are you looking?

Comment: In my home directory @Mark

Comment: Where exactly? and what do you expect to see in there?  There is one in ~/Library/Developer but that might not have the data you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9539602/4905253) and [this](https://superuser.com/a/710569), it seems that `~/Developer` folder no longer exist.

There's no problem unless you have scripts that expect that folder to exist or you're reading old guides / documentation that no longer apply to the new Xcode tools and command line tool packaging and locations.